# What breadboard simulation software is this?

Tags: simulation, layout, breadboard, software

I'm not familiar with what software is available and cannot recognize the origin of this diagram. Does anyone know what software this is? I'm only guessing that it can perform simulation; it may just be for layout.

[image]

Comment: Looks like Fritzing. Note that Fritzing is generally disliked on EE.SE because it's very hard to read compared to real schematics.

Comment: Looks like Fritzing.  I don't recommend using it.  Wiring diagrams (like in your example) hide information.  When designing or troubleshooting a circuit, you need to see the function of each connection.  With a wiring diagram, you see no functionality.  You have to flip back and forth from circuit to datasheet to wiring diagram.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn to use something like [KiCad](https://kicad.org/) [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @JRE Nice suggestion in general, but keep in mind that KiCad is not designed for newbies. It assumes a certain EE knowledge. Moreover the sheer amount of options is daunting. For an absolute beginner without the guidance of a teacher can be a motivation-killer. Fritzing *can be used* as a very stripped down circuit-CAD application without "harm"....

Comment: ... @JRE The only problematic thing is that people assume wiring diagrams is the "right way" (or "one right way") engineers communicate about circuits. And that **rightfully** annoys them a lot. It used to annoy me a lot, too, but I'm a teacher now and *patience* has become my second name! ;-)

Comment: The biggest down side to starting with Fritzing is that you will start to hit its limits and have to switch to different software anyway. You invest time learning how to use an inadequate tool.  Then more time trying to work around its inadequacies.  At some point, you realize that you are spending more time fighting the software than in getting things done.  At this point, you have to switch to something more capable - and invest time in learning how to do basic things all over again.

Comment: By the way, the layout shown in OP's picture is an excellent example why Fritzing *encourages bad designs*. For example, the electrolytic cap's leads aren't as rigid or probably not even as short as the diagram suggests, and every one would've just connected the cap directly to the positive power rail *in the same row as the 555's pin 2*, instead of putting it somewhere else, completely, and the resistor directly to ground. That would be the more "native" way of wiring things, if you've ever touched a breadboard, but **also** have been the logically right thing to do, if you had seen the …

Comment: … schematic and understood which purpose the cap and the resistor serve. Anyway, what I find insufferable is that fritzing (at least in every wiring diagram I've seen) doesn't show part names; it makes talking about things unnecessarily complicated ("the resistor on the right") and building unnecessarily hard. It's a bad practice. And it would be *so* easy to fix. Oh, and while I can certainly get out my color code table and reverse engineer the resistors, there's no standard when it comes to LEDs or capacitors, so this wiring diagram not even fulfills the job of unambiguously defining a build

Comment: NB: do not confuse "Fritzing" with "wiring diagram". Fritzing can show the circuit as schematic or PCB layout too.

Wiring diagrams are useful to help people construct a circuit you wish to teach them. It's one thing to build a breadboard circuit from a schematic, another thing entirely to have a reference showing you what it's supposed to look like when finished. You can take this wiring diagram, recreate it in Fritzing, then switch to schematic view to see the normal way of sharing electrical circuits for discussion.

Comment: @JRE I'm self taught in programming mainly in C++; I've tried a few times to learn Assembly which is a challenge, I have a good background in both Math and Physics. Most people who learn to be software developers care more about the Interface of devices than its implementation. They just want to know what it does and not how it does it. I'm the opposite, I care about both parts but I've always struggled to see how the physics portion causes the hardware to work with the appropriate software to drive it. ...(continue)

Comment: @JRE I have seen Ben Eaters youtube videos on how to build an 8-bit pc. That gave me a lot of insight. I also found a website that offers free courses without (grades or certs) that takes the approach of building a simulated pc from Nand gates all the way up to making an OS and writing applications and games such as Tetris; their site is called Nand2Tetris. Since I don't have access to bread boards to build simple circuits I've been looking on line for simulators to build the bread board versions of the gates, controllers and other components as I go through that course. ...(continue)

Comment: JRE I found one that was by Autodesk but it is an online version only; it is limited but I was able to get a few logical circuits to work through the simulation such as the and, or and not gates, but when I started to work on the Xor gate I was having issues with it and the site lags very badly. I kept searching for other programs that were "online" but installable but didn't cost a fortune either, then I found your comment here. I've installed the program and I have yet to test it out and work with it but from the looks of their website, I think I'm going to like it. One of the best comments!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is most likely [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/).

It is an educational free software quite popular among newbies and teachers. It can draw wiring diagrams like the one you posted, or true schematics and even PCB layouts.

It can't simulate the circuit, though.

As Felthry and JRE said in comments, using Fritzing is frowned upon on this site and by professional engineers because of the habit of newbies to post wiring diagrams instead of schematics.

A wiring diagram is to a schematic what a sketch of the exterior of a building is to its blueprints. It only gives a very partial and incomplete view of the thing you are going to build. So it is usually quite useless for understanding the real working of a circuit.

Fritzing in itself it is NOT a bad tool for a newbie, if you understand its purpose. *It can* be used to draw not too terrible schematics and this won't anger people here.

Just avoid asking questions describing your problem using a wiring diagram instead of a true schematic. This will *rightfully* annoy many engineers and even make some of them mad.

It's like a little kid showing his parents a crayon drawing of his electronic toy asking "how do it work this?". The parents are probably going to laugh at his naivety with affection. Of course if a teenager or a grown-up shows a wiring diagram to an EE with the same naivety, maybe "requiring" a coherent answer to his problem, the effect can be *drastically* different!

BTW, I've seen not many things that make most people here get annoyed so much as seeing a wiring diagram instead of a schematic (You are warned! :-)

Note: although seemingly the same thing, posting a photo of a *real breadboard* with a *real circuit* built on it (*together with its schematic*) will sometimes be useful to diagnose problems related to the actual wiring.